# Find $N$ so that the sequence is the product of three consecutive numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math

> Find the smallest natural number $N$ such that $13 \cdot 17 \cdot N$ is the product of three consecutive natural numbers.

$x(x+1)(x+2) = 13 \cdot 17 \cdot N$.

So let $x=N$, then, $N+1 = 13$ and $N+2 = 17$.

I am unsure how to proceed, can I get a hint?

Comment: I am not surprised that you do not know how to proceed. $N+1=13$ and $N+2=17$ are irreconcilable statements.

Comment: Why do you let $x=N$? That is an extra assumption...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By finding the gcd of 13 and 17 you can find a solution to $13x-17y=1$. In this case $x=4,y=3$.

Consider $N=3\cdot 4 \cdot 50$

$$13 \cdot 4 =52,17\cdot 3=51$$

$$x=50 \rightarrow x(x+1)(x+2)=50\cdot 51\cdot 52 = 13\cdot 17 \cdot (3\cdot 4\cdot 50)=13\cdot 17 \cdot N$$

Hence smallest value of $N=3\times 4\times 50 = 600$

Solutions for $13x-17y=2$ would be of the form $x=8+13k,y=6+17k$.For $k=-1,x=-5,y=-11$ which is the lowest that we can get for the given case. Hence there doesn't exist any lower solution.

Comment: Note that this doesn't exclude the possibility that there is a lower solution appearing from $13x+17y=2$. You have to check that this is indeed the lowest such $N$.

Comment: @Arthur Solutions for that would be of the form $x=8+13k,y=6+17k$.For $k=-1,x=-5,y=-11$ which is the lowest that we can get for the given case. Hence there doesn't exist any lower solution.

Comment: I know. But the check _must_ be done in order to have a correct answer.

Comment: @Arthur Yes you are right. I have edited my answer

Comment: The alternative attempt would be to try N=(13.17-1)(13.17-2) which is much too large.